# How to post data to php file and get result using ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Hi I want to post data to php and reseve php result and result post to html div tag. Please give me sample code. Thank you sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, suppose you can to make an AJAX request when clicked to an `a` tag with class `link`, HTML looks like:

```
<div class="content"></div>
<a href="#" class="link">Ajax Request</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.link').click(function(){       
    $.ajax({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: { 'data_id': 'YOUR_DATA' }, //Data you want to send
        success: function(response) {
           $(".content").append(response);
        }
});
```

**ajax.php:**

```
$data=$_GET["data_id"];
//Do some process and echo what you want to sendback
echo $data;
```

**Note:** Your must include jQuery in your document

Comment: Can you give sample code full sample code

Comment: HTML: http://pastebin.com/U4bPSvLK
PHP (ajax.php) : http://pastebin.com/mXUt4V48

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helps you, does it?